# Do software dev recruiters pay attention to LinkedIn group participation?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, recruitment, linkedin

I've been advised by a job-search consultant-type that recruiters pay attention to participation in LinkedIn groups as a way to pick out candidates to contact.  For recruiters interested in software developers, wouldn't they instead pay attention to Stack Overflow and the like?  Or do they *also* pay attention to the LinkedIn groups?

Comment: Probably to gauge your interest in the field and your participation with community to see how much learning potential you have

Comment: Whenever I see someone with a lot of SE, Linkedin, ... activity, I wonder who payed for their time on those communities...

Comment: @Daniel what if they were doing it in their spare time or on their lunch break?

Comment: @520: the **IF** - that´s exactly what I wonder about ...

Comment: @Daniel do you look at the timestamps of their activity? Then you wouldn't have to wonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will vary greatly.

In my experience, I haven't gotten or not gotten a job based on group participation as a software developer.  I get many inquiries as to my availability each week, but your mileage may vary.

Now for role such as project manager or agile coach, group membership and or participation is much more important.